# Problems with shifted double bonds in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

The next code produces the molecule shown in the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig[bond join=true,atom sep=2em]{\charge{[extra sep=4.5pt]0=\.}{}(-[4]*6(=-=-=-))(=^[2]O)}

\end{document}
```

[image: molecule]

As you can see there are two problems related with the shifted double bond. The first problem is that the oxygen atom remains in the same place (upper arrow). The second problem (bottom arrow) is that the joint between single and double bond doesn't look fine, even when I'm using the comand: *bond join = true*. Any recommendations for this issues?

Comment: Indepenent of your present problem, maybe you can have a look here (https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home)

Comment: I didn't know that tool, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[bond join=true,atom sep=2em]{
  \charge{[extra sep=4.5pt]0=\.}{}(-[4]*6(=-=-=-))(=^[2,,,,line cap=rect]{O\rule{2pt}{0pt}})
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. Please, can you put the explanations how do you have solved the problem. My it is +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks. The addition of the `\rule{2pt}{0pt}` increased the width by 2pt and pushed the O left by 1pt.
`line cap=rect` from tikz filled the gap.